# How does the difference quotient with a square root in the numerator end up with square roots in the denominator?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

I don't understand when

I apply the difference quotient to: $f(x) = \sqrt{x} $   , to get:

$$\frac{\sqrt{x+h} - \sqrt{x}}{h}$$

To simplify it.. How does it end up like this?:

$$\frac{x + h - x}{h \sqrt{x+h} + \sqrt{x}}= \frac{1}{\ 2\sqrt{x}}$$

How do the sqrt's work when moving them from the numerator to the denominator?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the second line, where did $h$ go?

Comment: Man i don't know. I'm looking at the solutions my professor  posted and that's how he showed it. His note's are making this so much more confusing than it should be :(

Comment: @Ethan how do you format that correctly?

Comment: I think you need to slow down on posting questions and focus on one of them, also if you can't understand what he wrote, it might be best to try simplifying it yourself instead of trying to figure out what he did, I suggest multiplying the numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}$ and then simplifying.

Comment: Here's a YouTube video that might help: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a-pXE1nfE14

Comment: That's what he did $ \frac{\sqrt{x+h} - \sqrt{x}}{h} = \frac{\sqrt{x+h} - \sqrt{x}}{h} \frac{\sqrt{x+h} + \sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+h} + \sqrt{x}}. $

Comment: The final line appears to be incorrect.  Not sure if that's a transcription error or not.  If not then that might be par of your confusion.

Comment: @ScottH.I double checked it on the "solutions" but I have the same problem in my notes and my notes have 1/2sqrt(x). Figures he would give me the wrong answer.

Comment: You should not have the minus sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x}}{h}=\frac{(x+h)-x}{h(\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x})}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}}$

So by letting h go to 0 we get

$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x}}{h}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$

Comment: Ok that makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it makes sense. Your welcome.

Comment: But why do you want the square root in the denominator?

Answer (score 1):

actually when you want to get $ \frac{\sqrt {x+h}-\sqrt x)} h$ you don't use the limit
it goes like this:

- multiply the nominator and denominator by $\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt x$

which at the end will result in $\frac 1 {\sqrt {x+h} + \sqrt x}$

- $h$ shouldn't be treated as approaching zero unless you were told it is OR you're finding the derivative by definition.

Let me know if it helped ya :)

Comment: please try to format your answers properly

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily want the square root in the denominator, you want h out of it because it'll be set to 0 to find the limit. Since you can't divide by 0 you must factor h out of the denominator.